# React Native Android Project not bulding when adding Kochava Library

Tags: android, react-native, expo

On the latest build of bare-workflow-expo-react-native project. I tried adding Kochova library: https://support.kochava.com/sdk-integration/reactnative-sdk-integration/
But the build is failing on android.

I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find :KochavaCore:.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-kochava-tracker
   > Could not find :KochavaTracker:.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-kochava-tracker
   > Could not find :KochavaTrackerEvents:.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-kochava-tracker
   > Could not find :KochavaTrackerEngagement:.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-kochava-tracker
   > Could not find :KochavaTrackerDatapointNetwork:.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-kochava-tracker
```

I followed the steps and added to `app/build.gradle` the following:

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.1.0'
 implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appset:16.0.0'
```

The repositories include the following in `build.gradle`:

```
mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup 'com.facebook.react'
            }
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
```

I'm running:
"react-native": "0.70.5",
and
"expo": "^47.0.13".

Comment: Having the same issue trying to upgrade kochava from 1.5.1 to 2.1.2

react-native-kochava-tracker